# MS Access using VBA in a SQL IN clause

Tags: sql, vba

I'm trying to pass some values from a vba function to an SQL.

This is my SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy3
WHERE ID IN (getList("1 and 2"));
```

this is the definition of the vba function:

```
Function getList(Measure As String) As String
```

when I call the function I get: 1,2,3 as a String.

if I run the SQL as

```
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy3
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3);
```

it works fine, but combining the two doesn't work. So I guess the String type is wrong, can you please help?

Comment: Is this an Access SQL query or is a query formed in VBA code?

Comment: It is a real Access SQL Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your query does not work like you expect it. Your function returns a string, so the query performed is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy3
WHERE ID IN ("1,2,3");
```

Notice the quotation marks. Basically you are comparing an integer to a string and so doesn't return any results.

What you can do is use the INSTR function to see if the ID can be found in the string:

```
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy3
WHERE INSTR(getList("1 and 2"),ID);
```

Now it will work because ID 1 can be found in the string "1,2,3" so the INSTR function will return the position where it can be found.