# Determine the type of a listbox bound column VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am building a SQL string based on the selections in a multiselect listbox and to accomplish this, I am trying to determine whether or not the type of the bound column of my listbox is a string.
I wrote the following code:

```
    If lstBox.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then
    lstVar = lstBox.ItemData(i)
    Debug.Print VarType(lstVar)
    For Each varItem In lstBox.ItemsSelected
        strCrit = strCrit & "," & "'" & lstBox.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
    Next varItem

    ' remove first comma
    strCrit = Mid(strCrit, 2)
```

On the debug.print VarType statement, it always results in the string type, even if the bound column of the list box is an autonumber field. I want to know if the type is numerical rather than string so that later, in my SQL statment

```
 SELECT … FROM … WHERE … IN (x,y,z)
```

I can write the correct WHERE … IN criteria that won't later result in a type mismatch. Is there a way to accurately determine variable type for a list box bound column? Perhaps I should approach this another way, by looking at the type of the row source of the list box. Because I am using this function to iterate through multiple list boxes that build the where criteria, I need it to be dynamic and flexible for the reality that some list box bound columns will be numeric while others will be strings, so I can't just hard code it into the loop.

Comment: How is `lstVar` declared?

Comment: lstVar is declared as a variant

Comment: In any case, a selected item in a `ListBox` is always going to be a `String`. You can't get the underlying type, because it's gone at that point: it's a `String`. Get the ID into the listbox, pull the ID, then query the source using that ID; the recordset will have the correct types.

Comment: The ID is in the listbox and I have pulled it. But I'm just not sure how to designate to not use quotes around the IN criteria without determining the type of the bound column. Otherwise I get a query like `SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE myID IN  ('1','2','3')` which results in a type error. I want `...myID IN (1,2,3)` but if I have an actual string, I want the function to work there as well `...myStr IN ('a','b','c')`

Comment: Not familiar with Access/DAO, but it looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23679319/1188513) might help. If possible, prefer a parameterized query so that the database engine can work out the correct parameter type, instead of string-concatenating the where clause. Benefits include correctness, performance, ...and [security](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Good suggestion but I'm afraid it won't work. For example, ID 1 would be in the string ("2,6,10") but that doesn't mean 1 is one of the IDs in the list.

Comment: You could insert the IDs you're after in a temp table, then select from your source and join with that temp table. Basically drop the `IN("foo", "bar")` path altogether

Comment: Using `LIKE` or `InStr` with lists generally works like this: 1 & ",*" LIKE "2,6,10" & ",". Then you don't have a problem with 1 matching 10, you just can't match on strings containing comma's or like wildcards. To avoid the problem with like wildcards you can use InStr instead. You can also build a query with a variable amount of parameters.

Comment: Regarding your sample `SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE myID IN ('1','2','3')`: Wouldn't it be more important/clever to know the datatype of `myID` and then building the list regarding that datatype instead of the listbox's values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a bound list box, you can get the type of the bound column by using the underlying recordset.

See the following code:

```
Dim rs As Object 'most likely DAO.Recordset but could be ADODB.Recordset
With lstBox
    Set rs = .Recordset
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(.BoundColumn - 1).Type
End With
```

This prints a `DAO.DataTypeEnum` if you're working with a DAO recordset, or an `ADODB.DataTypeEnum` if you're working with an ADODB one. These are easy to convert to VBA data types.

Mathieu Guindon's point about using parameters remains, though. I strongly recommend it.